# convert json_encode data to javascript array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am send some data from php by json_encode to javascript. this is the data

```
[{"albumid":"ASaBFzCtl8","albumname":"anni","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"2"},{"albumid":"EmgsZ43ehT","albumname":"testalbum","type":"1","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"Jf4H4SvFGk","albumname":"test2album","type":"3","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"k3pacBSmIl","albumname":"testalbumpvt","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"0"}]
```

after enoding in php it is something like that

```
       //json_encode($data);

"[{\"albumid\":\"ASaBFzCtl8\",\"albumname\":\"anni\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"2\",\"itemcount\":\"2\"},{\"albumid\":\"EmgsZ43ehT\",\"albumname\":\"testalbum\",\"type\":\"1\",\"access\":\"1\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"},{\"albumid\":\"Jf4H4SvFGk\",\"albumname\":\"test2album\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"1\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"},{\"albumid\":\"k3pacBSmIl\",\"albumname\":\"testalbumpvt\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"2\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"}]"
```

i am receiving this in jquery

```
$.post("demo.php",
  {
    token:"123456789"
  },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

what can i do so that i get all data in javascript array
i need type value out of it and looking something like that

```
var typevalue = jsonArray['type'];
// typevalue = 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). The response defines an Array of Objects, so you'll have to specify a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) for each layer -- `data[0].type` or `JSON.parse(data)[0].type` if jQuery hasn't already parsed the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have parsed json here's how you loop it:

```
$.each(data, function(key, album){
    console.log(album.type);
});
```

To grab the first type in the list simply do:

```
var albumType = data[0].type;
```

Full solution with parsing:

```
$.post("demo.php", {
    token: "123456789"
},

function (data, status) {
    $.each(data, function (key, album) {
        alert(album.type);
    });

}, "json"); //datatype defined here
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending array from php as-

```
json_encode($php_array);
```

Receive the array in js-

```
var js_array = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

$.each(js_array , function(idx,obj) {
    console.log(obj.type);
});
```

Comment: Sahil how can i get value of type out of it. in my case there is 4 type values first one is 3 after that 1 , 3 1

Comment: did you tried this code? This will alert all 3 values

Comment: i tried this alert(result.type) but it says undefined

Comment: it alert complete data value but i need some of it

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

1stly you can encode the array directly

```
  $sendData = JSON_encode(array(
    "albumId"=>"ASaBFzCtl8",
    "albumName"=>"anni",
     // etc
   ));
   echo $sendData;
```

2ndly in JS, you can parse the date with JSON_parse

```
 $.post("demo.php",
      {
        token:"123456789"
      },
      function(data,status){
        var json = JSON_parse(data);
        console.log(json.albumId); // or alert
      }
    );
```

Comment: sorry it is JSON.parse() and not JSON_parse()